# How to view the procedures in Netezza

Tags: netezza

How to view the procedures in Netezza?

In oracle , we can view with the help of below query.

select * from user_source where object_name=upper('PROC_NAME');

Answer (score 4):

The Netezza equivalent would be:

```
SELECT * FROM  _v_procedure WHERE procedure = 'PROC_NAME';
```

Answer (score 0):

On the left panel where the databases are shown click the database, click stored procedures, right click on the procedure, click edit procedure and the procedure will be seen on the right panel

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to view procedure signature is -

```
DB.SCHEMA(USER)=> show procedure <procedure name>
```